# How to add if statement on WordPress shortcode output

Tags: functions, shortcode, media-library

I'm making a shortcode function that collects data from WordPress media library

```
function byn_recent_resources_shortcode($atts, $content = null) {
    global $post;

    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
        'group'     => 'public',
        'num'     => '1',
        'orderby' => 'post_date',
    ), $atts));

  $args = array(
    'post_status' => 'inherit',
    'posts_per_page' => $num,
    'post_type' => 'attachment',
  );

  $args['tax_query'] = array(
    array(
      'taxonomy' => 'group',
      'terms' => array( $group ),
      'field' => 'slug',
    ),
  );

    $output = '';
    $posts = get_posts($args);

    foreach($posts as $post) {
        setup_postdata($post);
        $output .= '
      <article>
        <div class="thumbnail">

          // IF STATEMENT GOES HERE //

        </div>
      </article>
    ';
    }

    wp_reset_postdata();
    return '<div class="resource-list" id="resource-list"><div class="post-outer-wrap">'. $output .'</div></div>';
}
add_shortcode('byn-recent-resources', 'byn_recent_resources_shortcode');
```

Inside the **`<div class="thumbnail">`** output, I'm planning to enable **`<if>`** statement like so

```
<?php if ( wp_attachment_is_image( $id ) ) { ?>
  // Do option A
<?php } else { ?>
  // Do option B
<?php } ?>
```

How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use buffer, so instead of storing your markup in the `$output` variable and then print that variable inside your wrapper, you can store everything in buffer, save it all in a variable and return that variable

```
function byn_recent_resources_shortcode($atts, $content = null) {
    //...Put the same logic as in your question code

    //...Change, for the code below, what you have, from $posts declaration to the end of the code
    $posts = get_posts($args);
    ob_start();
    ?>
    <div class="resource-list" id="resource-list">
        <div class="post-outer-wrap">
    <?php
    foreach($posts as $post) {
        setup_postdata($post);        
    ?>
            <article>
                <div class="thumbnail">        ​
                   ​<?php if ( wp_attachment_is_image( $id ) ) { ?>
                       ​// Do option A
                   ​<?php } else { ?>
                      ​// Do option B
                   ​<?php } ?>
                ​</div>
            ​</article>
    <?php ​} ?>
        </div>
    </div>

    <?php
    $output = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    
    ​wp_reset_postdata();
    ​
    return  $output;
}
add_shortcode('byn-recent-resources', 'byn_recent_resources_shortcode');
```

`ob_start` will save the markup in a variable, including the product of the if statements, and then you just return that string.

Comment: It worked! Thank you

Comment: Cool! Can you accept the answer as correct please @Biyan

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use output buffering or drop out and in of PHP, then you could use bunch of functions, one containing the if statement, and use them to generate the html and the shortcode output.

```
function byn_recent_resources_shortcode($atts, $content = null) {
    $posts_html = array_map(
        'prefix_single_resource_html',
        get_posts(
            prefix_prepare_posts_query_args( $atts )
        )
    );
    wp_reset_postdata();

    return prefix_resources_list_html($posts_html);
}

function prefix_prepare_posts_query_args( array $atts ) {
    $args = array();
    
    // prepare $args from $atts here...

    return $args;
}

function prefix_resources_list_html( array $posts_html ) {
    return sprintf(
        '<div class="resource-list" id="resource-list">
            <div class="post-outer-wrap">%s</div>
        </div>',
        implode('', $posts_html)
    );
}

function prefix_single_resource_html( $post ) {
    setup_postdata($post);
    $id = 0; // where does the id come from?
    return sprintf(
        '<article>
            <div class="thumbnail">%s</div>
        </article>',
        prefix_single_resource_thumbnail_html($id)
    );
}

function prefix_single_resource_thumbnail_html( $id ) {
    if ( wp_attachment_is_image( $id ) ) {
        // returning early makes the explicit else statement unnecessary
        return 'image html';
    }
    return 'default value';
}
```

This has the added benefit that the code is split into smaller pieces, which makes the whole easier to understand. Also descriptive function names double as documentation for your code.